# What's the meaning of `taking advantage of any configured session pivoting`?

Tags: meaning

When I read this [document](https://www.coursehero.com/file/p6kffv4/msf-exploit-ms08067netapi-show-options-Module-options/):

> Communication with a host, similar to interacting via netcat, taking advantage of any configured session pivoting.

What's the meaning of `pivoting` there? what's the meaning of `configured session pivoting`?

*I have looked in a dictionary and I found these definitions:*

Pivoting: ......

Configured: .......

Session: ...........

*But I don't understand how these apply to this context because .................*

Comment: Hello, could you fill in the blanks that I've put in the question.

Comment: @JamesK Although I agree with your intent, I’m not sure that’s the right way to go about it; I think suggesting the edit would be better than doing it forcibly (if you will).

Comment: I'm trying something different.  Suggesting edits tends to get comments. This is quite a clear case where the dictionary will fail, so there is clearly a good question here. I'm not sure it is an ELL question though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't think that this question belongs to this site because it's related to specific computer science terms but ...

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pivot)

[**pivot**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pivot)

> (noun) a fixed point supporting something that turns or balances
>   (verb) to turn or twist

According to a quick search in Google, in relation with your context, you can find [this](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/pivoting/):

> **Pivoting** is the unique technique of using an instance (also referred
>   to as a ‘plant’ or ‘foothold’) to be able to move around inside a
>   network.

Such instance mentioned is considered the **pivot**, you can **move** inside a network opening a **session** in such element that **allows** you to connect to other nodes in the network.

But if you are taking that linked course, you should ask your tutors there instead of asking in an English Language site like this.
[image: Pivot]